# "Looping" the same SQL query for all entries grouped by date

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
+------------+-----------+------+----+
|    date    | player_id | rank | hp |
+------------+-----------+------+----+
| 2021-01-01 |         1 |    1 | 39 |
| 2021-01-01 |         5 |    2 | 20 |
| 2021-01-01 |         2 |    3 | 12 |
| 2021-01-01 |         3 |    4 | 48 |
| 2021-01-01 |         4 |    5 | 25 |
| 2021-01-02 |         1 |    2 | 42 |
| 2021-01-02 |         2 |    1 | 38 |
| 2021-01-02 |         3 |    4 | 21 |
| 2021-01-02 |         4 |    3 | 35 |
| 2021-01-02 |         5 |    5 | 28 |
| 2021-01-03 |         1 |    5 | 38 |
| 2021-01-03 |         3 |    2 | 31 |
| 2021-01-03 |         2 |    3 | 26 |
| 2021-01-03 |         4 |    4 | 22 |
| 2021-01-03 |         5 |    1 | 19 |
+------------+-----------+------+----+
```

When I use the following SQL code:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM `players` WHERE date='2021-01-01' ORDER BY rank ASC LIMIT 3) highest_rank
ORDER BY hp DESC LIMIT 2
```

The result will be this:

```
+------------+-----------+------+----+
|    date    | player_id | rank | hp |
+------------+-----------+------+----+
| 2021-01-01 |         1 |    1 | 39 |
| 2021-01-01 |         5 |    2 | 20 |
+------------+-----------+------+----+
```

My problem is the result is only for date='2021-01-01'. I want to do this for every day in the database. Ultimately, I want the result to look like this:

```
+------------+-----------+------+----+
|    date    | player_id | rank | hp |
+------------+-----------+------+----+
| 2021-01-01 |         1 |    1 | 39 |
| 2021-01-01 |         5 |    2 | 20 |
| 2021-01-02 |         1 |    2 | 42 |
| 2021-01-02 |         2 |    1 | 38 |
| 2021-01-03 |         3 |    2 | 31 |
| 2021-01-03 |         2 |    3 | 26 |
+------------+-----------+------+----+
```

How can this be done? I'm using MySQL/MariaDB if that makes any difference.

Comment: Post the task itself.

Comment: *I'm using MySQL/MariaDB if that makes any difference.* What is **precise** server version?

Comment: What should happen if there's less than two records (or none) for a day?

Comment: @Akina I use MariaDB 10. I'm not sure what you mean by posting the task itself?

Comment: @stickybit Then it should show fewer records (or none), it doesn't even need to show the dates that don't have any records. It should only work with what's recorded, kind of like GROUP BY but I'm a noob and never got that to work.

Comment: Try to use GROUP BY on the date and see if you can achieve what you want that way?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Credit goes to sticky bit in the comment section that provided a solution that almost worked. He retracted the suggestion because it wasn't the final solution, I think. But I tinkered with it and got it to work. Thank you, sticky bit!

For anyone interested in the solution:

```
SELECT date, player_id, rank, hp
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY date 
               ORDER BY hp DESC) h
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY date
                   ORDER BY rank ASC) r
        FROM players
    ) x
    WHERE r<=3
) y 
WHERE h<=2
```